# Slickgrid hide primary key Column

Tags: slickgrid, dataview

Is it possible to hide Slickgrid/dataview primary key column? If yes, how can we do that? Any example?

I have a Slickgrid that is using Dataview. I do not want to show the primary key column to user in some specific conditions.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the column definition, set the `width` property of your primary key to `0`. Doing so will visually hide the column.

Comment: Ok...Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Alone setting width  to Zero does not work. If you set all width, minWidth and maxWidth to Zero then it hides. Thank you very much.